# React Native & Redux : how and where to use componentWillMount()

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-native, redux, react-redux

I work on app with facebook login using react-native and redux. Right now I'm face to an issue :

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

So I think I have to use componentWillMount() just before my render method, but I don't know how to use it ..

containers/Login/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicatorIOS } from 'react-native';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../../actions';
import LoginButton from '../../components/Login';
import reducers from '../../reducers';
import { Card, CardSection, Button } from '../../components/common';


class Login extends Component {

  // how sould I use it ?
  componentWillMount() {

  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.auth);
    const { actions, auth } = this.props;
    var loginComponent = <LoginButton onLoginPressed={() => actions.login()} />;
    if(auth.error) {
      console.log("erreur");
      loginComponent = <View><LoginButton onLoginPressed={() => actions.login()} /><Text>{auth.error}</Text></View>;
    }
    if (auth.loading) {
      console.log("loading");
      loginComponent = <Text> LOL </Text>;
    }
    return(
      <View>
        <Card>
          <CardSection>
            { auth.loggedIn ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') : loginComponent }
          </CardSection>
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

the reducer :

```
import { LOADING, ERROR, LOGIN, LOGOUT } from '../actions/types';

function loginReducer(state = {loading: false, loggedIn: false, error: null}, action) {
  console.log(action);
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOADING:
      console.log('Inside the LOADING case');
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: true
      });
    case LOGIN:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: false,
        loggedIn: true,
        error: null,
      });
    case LOGOUT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: false,
        loggedIn: false,
        error: null
      });
    case ERROR:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: false,
        loggedIn: false,
        error: action.err
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }

}

export default loginReducer;
```

and the action :

```
import {
  LOADING,
  ERROR,
  LOGIN,
  LOGOUT,
  ADD_USER
} from './types';
import { facebookLogin, facebookLogout } from '../src/facebook';

export function attempt() {
  return {
    type: LOADING
  };
}

export function errors(err) {
  return {
    type: ERROR,
    err
  };
}

export function loggedin() {
  return {
    type: LOGIN
  };
}

export function loggedout() {
  return {
    type: LOGOUT
  };
}

export function addUser(id, name, profileURL, profileWidth, profileHeight) {
  return {
    type: ADD_USER,
    id,
    name,
    profileURL,
    profileWidth,
    profileHeight
  };
}

export function login() {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log('Before attempt');
    dispatch(attempt());
    facebookLogin().then((result) => {
      console.log('Facebook login success');
      dispatch(loggedin());
      dispatch(addUser(result.id, result.name, result.picture.data.url, result.picture.data.width, result.data.height));
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch(errors(err));
    });
  };
}

export function logout() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(attempt());
    facebookLogout().then(() => {
      dispatch(loggedout());
    })
  }
}
```

If you need more code here is my repo : 
https://github.com/antoninvroom/test_redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentWillMount` is one the first function to be run when creating a component. `getDefaultProps` is run first, then `getInitialState` then `componentWillMount`. Both `getDefaultProps` and `getInitialState` will be run only if you create the component with the react.createClass method. If the component is a class extending React.Component, those methods won't be run. It is recommended to use `componentDidMount` if you can instead of `componentWillMount` because your component can still be updated before componentWillMount and the first render.

You can find more info on the react component lifecycle [here](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/)

Also, it is recommended to set the state or the default props inside the class constructor or using `getDefaultProps` and `getInitialState`.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { bar: 'foo' };
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
}
```

**EDIT:** Here's the component handling login

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicatorIOS } from 'react-native';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../../actions';
import LoginButton from '../../components/Login';
import reducers from '../../reducers';
import { Card, CardSection, Button } from '../../components/common';

class Login extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // If user is already logged in
    if(this.props.auth.loggedIn) {
      // redirect user here
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // If the user just log in
    if(!this.props.auth.loggedIn && nextProps.auth.loggedIn) {
      // Redirect user here
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.auth);
    const { actions, auth } = this.props;
    var loginComponent = <LoginButton onLoginPressed={() => actions.login()} />;
    if(auth.error) {
      console.log("erreur");
      loginComponent = <View><LoginButton onLoginPressed={() => actions.login()} /><Text>{auth.error}</Text></View>;
    }
    if (auth.loading) {
      console.log("loading");
      loginComponent = <Text> LOL </Text>;
    }
    return(
      <View>
        <Card>
          <CardSection>
            { auth.loggedIn ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') : loginComponent }
          </CardSection>
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: For the login component am I obligated to do that ? I just want to login and going in Home View and get the state in Home view

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to Ajay's answer, you are looking to set the initial state in the component. To do so, you would set the state inside the [constructor function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor).

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: props.initialColor
    };
  }
```

If you have data that is fetched asynchronously that is to be placed in the component state, [you can use `componentWillReceiveProps`.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.auth !== nextProps.auth) {
    // Do something if the new auth object does not match the old auth object
    this.setState({foo: nextProps.auth.bar});
  }
}
```

Comment: I am on a login view and want to set state to "true" if user is logged in and going to the Home view if its true, did I need this constructor / componentWillReceive ?

Comment: If thats the case, I don't think you really need component state. I would navigate the user to the home screen if auth.loggedIn is true. Something like this:

    `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.auth.loggedIn) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
      }
    }`

You would also need to include it in componentDidMount:

    `componentDidMount() {
      if (this.props.auth.loggedIn) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
      }
    }`

Comment: Thank you buddy ! and in the Home container I have to put constructor ? or componentWillReceive ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do in the Home container, but if the data you want to set is fetched async, like in an API call, you can do that in componentWillReceiveProps. and if it is being passed to the component from a parent, then the state can be set in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

if you need more info componentWillMount()
read this https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/premounting_with_componentwillmount.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in my case how should I define my state in the componentWillMount() ?